# What simplifies an expression when `!` is applied to `&&` or `||`

Tags: java, boolean-operations

> 5.121 ***_*___** simplifies expression in which ! is applied to && or ||

This showed up on my quiz in Java. I have no idea what it is and it is not multiple choice. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 14):

The answer the teacher is probably looking for is [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). You can take an expression such as !p && !q and rewrite it as !(p || q), which is arguably easier to read. This is actually a universal law of booleans that is not particular to any language like java.

Comment: You beat me to it :) I would say that in general, it depends on what p & q are as to which one is easier, but using De Morgan's lets you switch between the two representations as required.

Comment: Yeah De Morgan's law is the answer! +1

Comment: I usually use De Morgan's to go the other way so I required fewer parentheses. It's a lot easier, IMO, to read a large if block if each boolean expression is on its own line and isn't nested. It's also easier if you can make them all `&&` or `||` too.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: The differences are very slight. As long as you don't do: Boolean result = (p) ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE :P